# Convert NSString with octal numbers to decimal int

Tags: iphone, nsstring, octal

I have an NSString with octal numbers:

NSString* octal = @"247";

I'd like to convert this to an integer in base 10.

If this were a hex number I could use NSScanner scanHex method, but there is no scanOct...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard C library has conversion functions for this purpose:

```
NSString* octal = @"247";

unsigned long value;
sscanf([octal UTF8String], "%lo", &value);

NSString* decimal = [@(value) stringValue];
```

`decimal` now contains the converted base 10 value.